# How can i create new instance of same activity without change satic variables in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, static, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

i have an activity with some static variables such as Bundle and etc,in my app i start new instance of current activity with different extras:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),ActivityMain.class);
                    intent.putExtra("massId",pi.publisherId);
                    intent.putExtra("username",pi.userName);
                    intent.putExtra("avatar", pi.avatar);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

and it start without any problem and load new data but when i press back button static variables have changed by new instance.i use view pager and i have to use some static variables.
how can i start multiple instance of one activity as each instance have a its own variables

Comment: If you want each instance to have it's own variables, then don't make them static.

Comment: i implement my senarios without static variables and it work like charm thanks Karakuri

Comment: Very well, I will transfer that to an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are not held by instances of a class; they are held by the class itself and are shared by all instances of the class. If you want each instance to have it's own variables, then don't make them static.